# Get unsat core with z3py for non-linear constraints

Tags: z3, z3py

I have a set of simple but non linear constraints like:

```
v0= Real('v0')
v1= Real('v1')
v2= Real('v2')
v3= Real('v3')
v4= Real('v4')
v5= Real('v5')
v6= Real('v6')
v7= Real('v7')
v8= Real('v8')
v9= Real('v9')
v10= Real('v10')
v11= Real('v11')
v12= Real('v12')
v13= Real('v13')
v14= Real('v14')
v15= Real('v15')
v16= Real('v16')
v17= Real('v17')
v18= Real('v18')
v19= Real('v19')

s = Solver()
s.set(unsat_core=True)

s.add(v0>=0, v0<=1)
s.add(v1>=0, v1<=1)
s.add(v2>=0, v2<=1)
s.add(v3>=0, v3<=1)
s.add(v4>=0, v4<=1)
s.add(v5>=0, v5<=1)
s.add(v6>=0, v6<=1)
s.add(v7>=0, v7<=1)
s.add(v8>=0, v8<=1)
s.add(v9>=0, v9<=1)
s.add(v10>=0, v10<=1)
s.add(v11>=0, v11<=1)
s.add(v12>=0, v12<=1)
s.add(v13>=0, v13<=1)
s.add(v14>=0, v14<=1)
s.add(v15>=0, v15<=1)
s.add(v16>=0, v16<=1)
s.add(v17>=0, v17<=1)
s.add(v18>=0, v18<=1)
s.add(v19>=0, v19<=1)
s.add(v0==v1*v4)
s.add(v4==(v5+v6+v19)-(v5*v6+v5*v19+v6*v19)+(v5*v6*v19))
s.add(v6==v7*v11)
s.add(v11==(v12+v15+v18)-(v12*v15+v12*v18+v15*v18)+(v12*v15*v18))
s.add(v15==(v16+v17)-(v16*v17))
s.add(v12==v13*v14)
s.add(v7==(v8+v9+v10)-(v8*v9+v8*v10+v9*v10)+(v8*v9*v10))
s.add(v1==(v2+v3)-(v2*v3))
```

(this is basically probability computation)

I want to add a set of contraints like

```
v0_pred = Bool('v0_pred')
s.add(Implies(v0_pred, v0==0.0046))

v19_pred = Bool('v19_pred')
s.add(Implies(v19_pred, v19==0.015))

v16_pred = Bool('v16_pred')
s.add(Implies(v16_pred, v16==0.0094))

v12_pred = Bool('v12_pred')
s.add(Implies(v12_pred, v12==0.0172))

v5_pred = Bool('v5_pred')
s.add(Implies(v5_pred, v5==0.0038))

result = s.check(v0_pred,v19_pred,v16_pred,v12_pred,v5_pred)
```

and to track these 5 constraints into the unsat core. But then, more often than not, the solver reports that it cannot find a solution (*unknown*). If I do just `s.add(v0==0.0046, v19==0.015, v16==0.0094, v12==0.0172, v5==0.0038)`, it works excellently and quickly finds a solution (*sat*). But using just `s.add()` I cannot get the unsat core for unsat cases. What am I doing wrong?

UPD:
Example of the "unknown" problem with `Solver.assert_and_track()`:

```
from z3 import *

def is_number(s):
    try:
        float(s.numerator_as_long())
        return True
    except AttributeError:
        return False

v0= Real('v0')
v1= Real('v1')
v2= Real('v2')
v3= Real('v3')
v4= Real('v4')
v5= Real('v5')
v6= Real('v6')
v7= Real('v7')
v8= Real('v8')
v9= Real('v9')
v10= Real('v10')
v11= Real('v11')
v12= Real('v12')
v13= Real('v13')
v14= Real('v14')
v15= Real('v15')
v16= Real('v16')
v17= Real('v17')
v18= Real('v18')
v19= Real('v19')

s = Solver()

s.set(unsat_core=True)

s.add(v0>=0, v0<=1)
s.add(v1>=0, v1<=1)
s.add(v2>=0, v2<=1)
s.add(v3>=0, v3<=1)
s.add(v4>=0, v4<=1)
s.add(v5>=0, v5<=1)
s.add(v6>=0, v6<=1)
s.add(v7>=0, v7<=1)
s.add(v8>=0, v8<=1)
s.add(v9>=0, v9<=1)
s.add(v10>=0, v10<=1)
s.add(v11>=0, v11<=1)
s.add(v12>=0, v12<=1)
s.add(v13>=0, v13<=1)
s.add(v14>=0, v14<=1)
s.add(v15>=0, v15<=1)
s.add(v16>=0, v16<=1)
s.add(v17>=0, v17<=1)
s.add(v18>=0, v18<=1)
s.add(v19>=0, v19<=1)
s.add(v0==v1*v4)
s.add(v4==(v5+v6+v19)-(v5*v6+v5*v19+v6*v19)+(v5*v6*v19))
s.add(v6==v7*v11)
s.add(v11==(v12+v15+v18)-(v12*v15+v12*v18+v15*v18)+(v12*v15*v18))
s.add(v15==(v16+v17)-(v16*v17))
s.add(v12==v13*v14)
s.add(v7==(v8+v9+v10)-(v8*v9+v8*v10+v9*v10)+(v8*v9*v10))
s.add(v1==(v2+v3)-(v2*v3))


v0_pred = Bool('v0_pred')
s.assert_and_track(v0==0.0046, v0_pred)

v19_pred = Bool('v19_pred')
s.assert_and_track(v19==0.015, v19_pred)

v16_pred = Bool('v16_pred')
s.assert_and_track(v16==0.0094, v16_pred)

v12_pred = Bool('v12_pred')
s.assert_and_track(v12==0.0172, v12_pred)

v5_pred = Bool('v5_pred')
s.assert_and_track(v5==0.0038, v5_pred)


result = s.check()

print result
if result == z3.sat:
    m = s.model()
    for d in m.decls(): 
        if (is_number(m[d])):
            print "%s = %s" % (d.name(), float(m[d].numerator_as_long())/float(m[d].denominator_as_long()))
        else:
            print "%s = %s" % (d.name(), m[d])
elif result == z3.unsat:
    print s.unsat_core()
```

It returns me `unknown`, while it is `sat`, and is solved if using `Solver.add()` instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use `assert_and_track` to track them into unsat cores. See this: https://z3prover.github.io/api/html/classz3py_1_1_solver.html#ad1255f8f9ba8926bb04e1e2ab38c8c15

## Handling non-linearity

Since your problem includes non-linear constraints, z3 will possibly have hard time handling those with default settings. Heuristic selections depend on a lot of factors and picking the right tactics is more of an art. For the problem you posted, the following works:

```
t = z3.Then('simplify', 'qfnra-nlsat')
s = t.solver()
result = s.check()
```

With other problems, your mileage might vary. But I suspect the above tactic should work for you so long as the structure of your problem stays the same.

Comment: Thanks, this solved my problem. But I don't understand, what is the difference in using s.add(Implies..) and s.assert_and_track() ? Do they use different solvers in the background?

Comment: No, sorry, after more experiments, I am running into the same problem -- the solver does not solve the same set of constraints (gives unknown) that it handles easily with just s.add().

Comment: Please post a minimal-working-verifiable example. (i.e., one that we can load to z3 directly) with all the imports etc. written.

Comment: Many thanks! It works with the Tactics trick. Where can I find some reference about using tactics? And can it be applied in the same way with the Optimize() solver, instead of Solver() ?

Comment: I don't think tactics are that well documented, if at all. You might want to ask at their github issues page. (https://github.com/Z3Prover/z3/issues)

Comment: There's some rudimentary documentation here: http://www.cs.tau.ac.il/~msagiv/courses/asv/z3py/strategies-examples.htm